# Next.js - Dealing with API Fetched Images

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

I'm using Next.js' [Image](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image) component with images fetched from an API.
Since I don't have the image dimensions, how should I handle the `width` prop requirement?

Should I ask the backend team to include width and height in the API response, or are there other solutions?

Comment: The `width` and `height` props of the `Image` component don't need to be the same as the image's real size, they should instead represent the size in which they are rendered in the frontend. If you have an image with a size of 1000x1000 and want to render it in a small square that will be max 600px wide in any viewport, then I'd set the width and height to `600`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some custom post fetch hooks on the server side to generate various variants of images and then you can utilize the required variant as you want